# Get a random element from an array in a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, random

I have seen a lot of results on google on how to get a random array index, but I have not been able to apply it to this scenario.

Consider the following:

```
my %hash;
my @array = {"foo", "bar", "poo"};

$hash->{mykey} = @array;
```

How would I get a random element from the array inside $hash->{mykey}? Something like the following code which does not work:

```
my $element = $hash->{mykey}[rand($hash->{mykey})];
```

EDIT: So the answers below are extremely informative for this. Compounding *my* issue in particular was that I was using the threads module, and completely forgot to share the arrays that I was appending to the hash elements! Due to this, the answers were not working for me right away.

After fixing that oversight, the solutions below worked perfectly.

Comment: Some advice: first, get your random selection code working where there are no threads involved; that way you won't keep wondering if they are causing the problem (they very likely aren't).  http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference is very helpful for internalizing all the ways to deal with references in perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three errors.

---

1. The following create an array with one element, a reference to a hash:

```
my @array = {"foo", "bar", "poo"};
```

You surely meant to use

```
my @array = ("foo", "bar", "poo");
```

---

2.

```
$hash->{mykey} = @array;
```

is the same thing as

```
$hash->{mykey} = 3;
```

You can't store arrays in scalars, but you can store a reference to one.

```
$hash->{mykey} = \@array;
```

---

3.  It would be

```
rand(@a)    # rand conveniently imposes a scalar context.
```

for an array, so it's

```
rand(@{ $ref })
```

for a reference to an array. That means you want the following:

```
my $element = $hash->{mykey}[ rand(@{ $hash->{mykey} }) ];
```

Or you can break it down into two lines.

```
my $array = $hash->{mykey};
my $element = $array->[ rand(@$array) ];
```

---

All together, we have the following:

```
my @array = ( "foo", "bar", "poo" );
my $hash = { mykey => \@array };

my $element = $hash->{mykey}[ rand(@{ $hash->{mykey} }) ];
```

Comment: note that if the array is shared, the two operations (getting the length of the array and getting a random element) are not performed atomically, so could try to get a just-removed element past the end of the array if the array is not locked.

Comment: @ysth, I was very confused as to why you would mention that, but I see threads have been mentioned in other comments. Nothing a simple `lock @$array;` can't handle.

Comment: Just FYI, you still have a hash vs hashref problem floating around.

Comment: @Joel Berger, Oops, fixed. I won't bother mentioning the fact that the OP used the wrong sigil.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your first problem is the construction of your data structure:

```
#always
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my @array = ("foo", "bar", "poo");

$hash{mykey} = \@array;
```

You should probably read [perldoc perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut) to get comfortable with Perl's semantics relating to nested data structures (references).

At this point you can create the structure all at once, which is probably what you mean:

```
#always
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ( 
  mykey => ["foo", "bar", "poo"],
);
```

To find the length you just use the regular Perl mechanics for getting the length of the array:

```
my $length = @{ $hash{mykey} };
```

and then the random element

```
my $elem = $hash{mykey}[rand $length];
```

Comment: Is it thread-safe to use \@array, since it will be a reference? I'm using the threads module, and in my code the hash element is accessed by several threads.

Comment: Also, how do I apply this to get the random element?

Comment: I'm not your guy on threads. I think that might be getting a little ahead of yourself if you still need practice on the language though.

Comment: If you can believe it, I've been working with Perl for several years now. Still though, I cannot grasp the references and de-referencing. It's getting a little embarrassing. :P

Comment: This isn't working so well for me. When I do this, I get the global symbol requires explicit package name error. I think it is due to the threads.

Comment: Well, sorry about that then. Again, I never use threads, so I really can't help you there. Sounds like you forgot a `my` or a `;` to me, but then again, I'm not one for threads.

Comment: Thanks for the help though Joel. It's appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting new errors revolving around sharing now. I think the problem might actually lay with sharing between threads. I'll revisit it tomorrow and see if your method works after i figure out how I am sharing the value incorrectly.